# Como executar um Recicle view em outras activitys

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-activity

Como eu coloco um recicle view ou um list view em alguma outras activity ?

**Exemplo:** criei um projeto  com nome X dai nele assim que  coloquei o layout como Empty activity e tal ele me gera um layout activity_main e uma classe  MainActivity padrão , dai blz se eu crio outros layouts exemplo b activity e classe B , tudo que rodo na classe B para que se mostre no layout B não aparece . O que devo fazer ?

Olhem a main:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private MyAdapter adapter;
    private List<RecyclerItem> listItems;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        //Generate sample data

        for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
            listItems.add(new RecyclerItem("Item " + (i + 1), "teste " + (i+1)));
        }

        //Set adapter
        adapter = new MyAdapter(listItems, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Essa linha seta o content view no xml activity_main, verifique se o seu código da classe b está setando no xml correto (R.layout.activity_b, por exemplo)
Outro erro pode ser caso as referencias estejão com o nome errado, por exemplo você colocou um EditText com o id et1 e chamou o id et2 que está em outro layout

Espero ter ajudado

Por favor coloque o código da classe b na pergunta, isso facilitará bastante

Comment: Guilherme , obrigado pela ajuda olha o outro código .

Comment: o codigo da man é a classe principal dai criei outra activity com nome inicio  public class inicio extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inicio);
    }
}  dai ele leva para esse código dessa tela com nome inicio nela que tinha que mostra o recicle , so que dai na primeira tela tem um botao que leva essa segunda , so que nessa segunda tela mostra em branco não mostra o recicle view